# Using environment variables in commands passed to screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

To execute a command in a detached screen I can do this (after creating a screen, `screen -dmS myscreen bash`):

```
screen -S myscreen -X stuff $'echo hello\n'
```

However this syntax messes with `$` for environment variables:

```
MSG="hello"
screen -S myscreen -X stuff $'echo $MSG\n' #doesn't work
```

What can I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a double-quoted string for the part that needs to expand a variable, and a dollar-quoted string for the part that contains the escape sequence, and concatenate them.

```
screen -S myscreen -X stuff "echo $MSG"$'\n'
```

Another option is to assign the newline string to a variable:

```
NL=$'\n'
screen -S myscreen -X stuff "echo $MSG$NL"
```

BTW, `MSG` is not an environment variable, it's just a shell variable. It doesn't become an environment variable unless you `export` it.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the second option. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, though it doesn't seem like a clean example...

```
MSG="hello"
screen -S myscreen -X stuff "echo $MSG
"
```